# Rxjava2 + Google SignIn In Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin, google-authentication, rx-java2

I am trying to integrate Google SignIn for Firebase in my application using RxJava approach. But for some reason it's slow. I am using nested Observables in my approach to solving this problem. Can someone suggest a better and efficient solution to this problem?

**This is a step-by-step walkthrough to my code**

The user clicks on Google SignIn Button

```
@OnClick(R.id.googleButton)
    void googleSignUpButtonClicked() {
        // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
        // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
        // options specified by gso.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

                    }
                } /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
```

The above was a simple copy paste from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin), for those interested.
Then in `onActivityResult()` I call my function which does the "SignIn":

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Again its a simple copy-paste from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin).

In `firebaseAuthWithGoogle()` my `Observable` Sign's-In the user and then the `Observer` attached to this `Observable` creates another observable which checks if the user exists in my firebase or not.

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);

        authenticateWithCredential = new DisposableObserver<AuthResult>() {
            private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
            private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

            @Override
            public void onNext(AuthResult authResult) {
                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                firebaseUser = authResult.getUser();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                //checkUserExists.dispose();
                checkIfUserExists(databaseReference, firebaseUser);
            }
        };

        FirebaseAuthorization.observableSignInWithCredential(mAuth, credential)
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(authenticateWithCredential);
    }
```

To check if the user exists or not.

```
public void checkIfUserExists(DatabaseReference databaseReference, FirebaseUser firebaseUser) {
        checkUserExists = new DisposableObserver<DataSnapshot>() {

            @Override
            public void onNext(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("GoogleFacebook", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putString("username", dataSnapshot.toString());
                    editor.apply();
                } else {
                    enterUsernameDialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                            .title("Almost There!")
                            .content("Give us an Awesome Username to Identify Yourself")
                            .inputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                                    InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME)
                            .positiveText("Submit!")
                            .inputRange(4, 16)
                            .canceledOnTouchOutside(false)
                            .alwaysCallInputCallback() // this forces the callback to be invoked with every input change
                            .input("Username", "", new MaterialDialog.InputCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onInput(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, CharSequence input) {
                                    if (input.toString().length() > 3 && input.toString().length() < 16) {
                                        dialog.getActionButton(DialogAction.POSITIVE).setEnabled(true);
                                    }
                                }
                            }).onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                                    //showIndeterminateProgressDialog(false);
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), dialog.getInputEditText().getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }).autoDismiss(false).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "I do Exist: Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "I do Exist: Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        observableSingleValueEvent(databaseReference.child("usersID").child(firebaseUser.getUid()))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(checkUserExists);
    }
```

Now first, this is too slow for some reason. Second, the toast: "I do Exist: Complete" gets called before the MaterialDialog `enterUsernameDialog` is even showed.

Can someone please describe a better approach to this than what I have done. :)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: 01/02/2017**

After tons of research on the topic, I finally made it work. Instead of the above mess of nested `Observables`, I used one of the `operators` from RxJava called `concatMap`. You can look it up if you want. I will just show you with the code below to help you better understand.

```
FirebaseAuthorization.observableSignInWithCredential(mAuth, credential)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .concatMap(new Function<AuthResult, Observable<DataSnapshot>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<DataSnapshot> apply(AuthResult authResult) throws Exception {
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        firebaseUser = authResult.getUser();
        progressDialog.setContent("Transferring Your User Data From Google To My App!");
        return observableSingleValueEvent(databaseReference.child("usersID").child(firebaseUser.getUid()));
    }
}).subscribe(checkUserExists);
```

I just merged the above nested observables in my question using `concatMap()` here, which results in one `Observer` called `checkUserExists`. There is no `authenticateWithCredential` Observer in this approach. This takes about less than a second to complete (Tested) and is much faster than my above approach.

If anyone has a better approach to this problem. Please do share :)